# Internet speed is capped at 100/100 Mbps (after BIOS update)

Tags: linux, networking

Not sure if the problem is actually related to the BIOS update, but i've recently done one including a CMOS reset.

I'm using Debian 10 (stable) and have a 500/200 Mbps internet connection, which is now seemingly capped at 100/100 Mbps.

I'm using the exact same UTP cable as before, but have tried with other cables as well and the result is the same.

My mobo is an [Asrock B450 Pro4](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/B450%20Pro4/index.asp#Specification), the related specs are as follows:

> - PCIE x1 Gigabit LAN 10/100/1000 Mb/s
> - Realtek RTL8111H

Output of `ethtool enp8s0`:

```
Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP AUI BNC MII FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

And `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: 70:85:c2:be:21:ba
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:38 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fcb04000-fcb04fff memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
```

Speedtest result:

[image]

I would like to figure out if this is a BIOS/hardware/ISP problem or a misconfiguration on my part.

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Have you checked in your contract if you don't have a download quota, maybe you hit it and now they are traffic shapping you,

Comment: So ethtool is saying you are running at 1,000 Mbps between your motherboard and the thing it is plugged into. Is this a cable modem or is there a router between you and the modem? If there is, check if there is any speed indication on the modem <-> router link (maybe orange rather than green led?). If you can log into the router and see what speed it thinks the link to the modem is. A disconnect and reconnect of the modem <-> router wouldn't hurt. After that a power cycle of the router and the modem would be the next thing to try.

Comment: @vfbsilva I have the same contract for years, there is no quota.

Comment: @icarus There is no modem included but there's a router. I'll check what speeds do i get if i bypass that and plug the internet cable directly into the mobo. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Most probable being something in your side, but keep in mind It is not unheard ISPs downgrading your CPE speed for a lower one once you reach some unusual bandwidth usage/are on the top 5% of more "power hungry" users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a router problem.

Restarted it, plugged the cable into another port and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Curious, I had a similar problem yesterday with **B450 M**, same onboard Realtek RTL8111, it started renegotiating link, dropping speed to 100Mbit. I thought it was a bad cable, but now I'm starting to be suspicious :)

Comment: Glad you have a solution. The output of ethtool was helpful in showing there was nothing obviously wrong with that link. What was missing was a diagram showing all the pieces of the setup, from the `internet cable`, the router, and any other computers.